# res.attachment(). Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/csv: "http://localhost:3000/post"

Tags: node.js, express, mime-types

Trying to trigger a download of the file.

```
res.attachment('./public/uploads/name-1540993539785.csv')
```

File is downloaded, but its content is just "uploads/name-1540995323357.csv" instead of real data.

Got an warning in console:

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/csv: "http://localhost:3000/post".

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is [`res.download`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.download) instead

`res.attachment` just sets the Content-Disposition header field to “attachment” and the Content-Type to the determined type. `res.download` also sends the file in question.